# c# emgu.cv rtsp memory leak i don't know how to solve it

Tags: rtsp

`your text`private void UpdateFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
`your text`{
`your text` if (capture == null || capture.Ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
`your text` {
`your text`     return;
`your text` }

```
       `your text` using (Mat frame = new Mat())
       `your text` {
       `your text`     capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
       `your text`     if (!frame.IsEmpty)
       `your text`     {
        `your text`        try
        `your text`        {
        `your text`            pictureBoxRTSP1.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBoxRTSP1.Image = `your text`frame.ToBitmap()));
              `your text`      Thread.Sleep(50);
            `your text`    }
            `your text`    catch { }
       
        `your text`    }
        `your text`    else
        `your text`    {
        `your text`    }
        `your text`    frame.Dispose();
      `your text`  }
  `your text`  }
```

this is my code
my memory is leaking until 8GB